# How do I get notifications for newly-created tickets in JIRA project, without enabling default notifications?

Tags: jira

I need to receive a notification whenever anyone creates a new ticket in my project in JIRA. But the admin has disabled the default notification feature.

I have been told to enable it by JIRA workflow notification.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a **Jira Automation** to send you a mail every time a ticket is created. Details [HERE](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-to-quot-watch-quot-a-project/qaq-p/1878475).

Regardless of the approach, worth to discuss with the jira administration on how to collaborate with them on notifications.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party plugins for this sort of functionality, but if you don't want to do that and your admin won't set up a notification schema, you have only three other choices that I'm currently aware of.

1. If you can get API access, you can [query a JIRA board for all issues](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/9.11.0/#agile/1.0/board-getIssuesForBoard).
2. Treat it as a workflow issue, and ensure that users opening new issues tag you, e.g. add `@Satish-The-Agile-PM` somewhere in the ticket, or simply have it added to your new-issue templates.
3. Periodically check your project and add yourself as a watcher to all issues.

The notification schema is often problematic because most organizations use JIRA for individual assignment rather than assigning to teams with a distribution list address, so it can become quite noisy. Whether or not the schema can be fine-tuned for just *your* projects so that the only person annoyed is you is something you may need to discuss with your administrator. As I consider the default JIRA approach to individual tickets an inherent anti-pattern, I've never explored using that particular option the way you describe, so I can't advise you on how to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Include the Custom Event in Notification Scheme.
But You will still need JIRA Administrator permission to configure the Notification Scheme so better to go with the 3rd option stated by Todd
"Periodically check your project and add yourself as a watcher to all issues."

Answer (score 0):

You can also try going to Project settings > Workflows, select create workflow, enter a name for your workflow and select the project where you want to use it then click create.

On the workflow editor page, select add transition and select the transition to receive a notification when a new ticket is created then click add action.

From the list of actions, select send email as you would need to configure the email notification settings; once done, save and publish the workflow.